# Dependency Injection for interfaces not known to Composition Root

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm using .NET Standard (2.1) class libraries and .NET Core 3.0 as a web API, so therefore the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library, though I suspect that doesn't quite matter.

General practice says my composition root (the API project) should coordinate all of the required implementations for the application interfaces.

How do I handle this when I have interfaces unknown to the Web API project that I want to set up injection for?

For example, a CQRS type dependency stack:

```
MyProject.Web.API, depends on:
    MyProject.MyService, which depends on:
        MyProject.MyService.Command
            MyProject.MyService.Command.Data
        MyProject.MyService.Query
            MyProject.MyService.Query.Data
```

MyProject.Web.API does not know that data projects exists, but each of those data projects has an `ICommandDbContext` or `IQueryDbContext` in there that I want to handle.

I can't set these up in the composition root without exposing the lower-level interfaces all the way to the Web API project, which is completely unnecessary for any other reason.  How can I handle DI on these lower level projects?

Comment: That would require those lower levels to expose an extension point to allow it to communicate with container to populate it with the required dependencies

Comment: @Nkosi - that's what I'm trying to avoid.  Seems like it should be possible to have some sort of orchestration further down than the composition root itself to deal with these cases, but I've never come across one.

Answer (score 1):

That would require those lower levels to expose an extension point to allow it to communicate with container to populate it with the required dependencies

For example

*MyProject.MyService*

```
public static class MyServiceProjectExtension {
    public IServiceCollection AddMyServiceDependencies(this IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<ICommandDbContext, CommandDbContext>(...);

        //...

        return services;
    }
}
```

And the Composition root calls the extension point from the service project

*MyProject.Web.API*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    services.AddMyServiceDependencies();

}
```

This means however that `MyProject.MyService` would take a direct dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractuions` in order to be aware of the DI framework.